What exactly is a sequential criterion?
My real analysis course teaches us a ton of different sequential criterions.
They teach us sequential criterion for limit points, closures, closed sets, compact sets, function limits, continuity, uniform continuity.
The problem is that I don't understand what a sequential criterion is in the first place, but they keep throwing more epsilon delta definitions at me. I was hoping someone could explain the basic idea of what a sequential criterion is in the first place, so that these theorems can be easily derived or memorised.

Continuity: $f : X \to Y$ is continuous at $x$ if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d(y, x) \leq \delta$ implies $d(f(y), f(x)) \leq \varepsilon$. An equivalent definition using sequences is that $f$ is continuous at $x$ if for every sequence $x_n \to x$ we have $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.

@Kakashi I know that but I what I don't know is what makes this a sequential criterion in the first place. What are the characteristics of something to be a sequential  criterion?

It's a sequential criterion because it expresses continuity in terms of convergent sequences.

@lin0258: It seems that, based on what kakashi said, a  criterion  for continuity  that uses convergent sequences is called a  sequential criterion for continuity. But continuity what just the specific property being looked at. It could have been a sequential criterion for dominated convergence or sequential criterion for integrability or some other mathematical property.
